# React multiple console.log?

Tags: reactjs, components, console.log

Im creating a function that sends an email based on the expiry date, however, upon trial, the function works fine but the email gets sent multiple times and the `console.log`  is shown multiple times. Does anyone know how to counteract?

```
if (product?.expiry) {
      var arr = []
      var today = new Date()
      var expiry = new Date(product?.expiry)
      var week = new Date(expiry.setDate(expiry.getDate() - 7))

      var template = {
        message: product.name + " is reaching expiry date",
        footer: "Expiry Date: " + week.toDateString()
      }

     const interval =  setInterval(() => {
      if (arr.length > 0) {
        clearInterval(interval)
        console.log(arr)
       }
        if (today !== expiry) {
          // actual emailing
            emailjs.send(SERVICE_API, TEMPLATE_API, template, PUBLIC_API)
            .then(function(response) {
              console.log('SUCCESS!', response.status, response.text);
            }, function(error) {
              console.log('FAILED...', error)
            });
            arr.push('found')
          }
     }, 1000)
 }
```

**ALERT:** I am aware that the function is sending the email when it is not the expiry date, i just want to fix up this console.log error

**rest of function: **

```
const expiryEmail = () => {
        if (today !== week) {
          emailjs.send(SERVICE_API, TEMPLATE_API, template, PUBLIC_API)
          .then(function(response) {
            console.log('SUCCESS!', response.status, response.text);
          }, function(error) {
            console.log('FAILED...', error)
          });
        }
      }

      setTimeout(() => {
        
      })
      useEffect(() => {
          if (!product) {
            return;
          }
          //problem is that the condition returns null first time around
          expiryEmail()
      },[])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use useEffect hook instead to set interval I am sharing the code try to use that

```
var today = new Date()
var expiry = new Date(product?.expiry)
var week = new Date(expiry.setDate(expiry.getDate() - 7))

var template = {
  message: product.name + " is reaching expiry date",
  footer: "Expiry Date: " + week.toDateString()
}


useEffect(()=>{
  if (today !== expiry) {
      emailjs.send(SERVICE_API, TEMPLATE_API, template, PUBLIC_API)
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log('SUCCESS!', response.status, response.text);
      }, function(error) {
        console.log('FAILED...', error)
      });
      arr.push('found')
  }
},[])
```

Comment: thanks for the useEffect code, code is a lot more cleaner and efficient, however the emails are coming with the product name being undefined

Answer (score 1):

The first condition inside your `setInterval` method's callback, ie.

```
if (arr.length > 0) {
        clearInterval(interval)
        console.log(arr)
}
```

does not have a `return` statement, which means it will continue on to your next `if` block, whose condition is satisfied because you are checking is today's date is not the same as `expiry` 's date, which as you **alerted** is a conscious decision, and therefore print the `console` message again.

Also, I hope by multiple you mean only twice, because that is what my answer applies for, if you meant more than that, I'd like to see the part that calls this method.

Again also, you should use Mayank's suggestion and process your code inside a `useEffect` block, much simpler.

Comment: so i have taken in the useEffect idea which does reduce the number of times that the email is sent, however it is now being sent twice where in both emails  product.name  is undefined. Ive added other parts of code

Comment: ive been able to deduce that the product is null in the useEffect - whats weird is when first rendered its null but when i go maybe add a comment or sumthn it works fine after I've saved that

Comment: If the `product` value is a state, what might be happening is when you start the project (npm/ yarn start), maybe the `useEffect` gets executed first and then the state value gets loaded. But when you comment and save, because React uses hot loading, your `product` state already has the previously initialized value and it prints that. I want to know where your product value is getting set.

Comment: Also you could pass the state `product` to the dependencies list of `useEffect` like this: ```useEffect( () => product && expiryEmail(), [product //this one])``` . What happens with this is, whenever your `product` value updates, that particular `useEffect` is called again.

Comment: Make sure you are not updating your `product` value unnecessarily as it will result in the same issue you had previously. Have fun~